# Browser-Incompatability with image alignment in CSS using YUI grid (Firefox + Opera)

Tags: html, css, cross-browser

I'm having trouble with the alignment of two images on the footer of my temporary website (http://www.rotimioyewole.com). I'm new to the YUI grid, which I think may be a factor.

It should look roughly like this (works correctly in Chrome and Safari, haven't tested IE yet):
(http://cl.ly/44fH)

But on FF and Opera look like this:
http://cl.ly/44aO

If I can have some sort of consistency then the website would at least be presentable. Ideally, I would also like to align both images on the same Y axis, as well as the text next to the icons. I had trouble figuring out how to search for a solution..can anybody help me?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the following

```
#footer h4
{
text-align:left;
//remove margin-left: 10px;
}

.icon {
float:left;
padding-right: 5px;
vertical-align: middle;
//remove position: absolute;
}

#contact {
text-align: left;
}
```

This should fix the problem in Firefox at the very least.

Comment: Thank you! This worked perfectly in all browsers. If I wasn't so new I'd boost your reputation :)

Comment: Anytime! I am new here too :)